# When User Meta amended update Title and Slug of Post programatically

Tags: wp-insert-post, wp-update-post

I have this code below which works perfectly, i.e. when adding a new User a post is programatically created in my CPT.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_member_employees' );

    function add_member_employees( $user_id ) {

    $user_meta=get_userdata($user_id); $user_roles=$user_meta->roles; 
    if (in_array("employees", $user_roles)){

    $new_member = array(
    'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST[ 'first_name' ] . " " . $_POST[ 'last_name' ] . " - "  .  date( 'F j, Y', current_time( 'timestamp' )) ),
    'post_author' => $user_id,
    'post_type' => 'employee',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_input' => array(
    'wpcf-employee-name' => $_POST[ 'first_name' ] . " " . $_POST[ 'last_name' ],
    'wpcf-employee-reg-date' => date( current_time( 'timestamp' )),
    ),
    );
wp_insert_post( $new_member );
}
```

}

What I'd like to do is if the User last_name is updated to then 'automatically' update just the post_title and post_name with the change of last name. I've looked at wp_update_post and googled a lot, but I've confused myself.

BTW the wpcf-employee-name is a Types field (Toolset plugin) and I'd like to update the last_name here too.

Could I in essence replicate the above but use wp_update_post? If this was the case would the slug be created using the code below (not sure about the date format):

```
'post_name' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST[ 'first_name' ] . "-" . $_POST[ 'last_name' ] . "-"  .  date( 'F j, Y', current_time( 'timestamp' )) ),
```

I'm not experienced when it comes to coding. So apologies if these are naive questions. Thank you for any help at all.